# Detect OS type using Javascript and perform something different per OS

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, browser

So I've looked around to try to find something suited to my situation, and whilst i've found lots of snippets that allow me to detect screen sizes, or a particular OS, solutions i've found are incomplete, or I cant figure out how to modify them so that they will work how I need them to.

My favorite solution is http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html but there is no android or windows phone detector which I need. upon trying to add it myself, I cant seem to get it to return Android instead of linux if I use

BrowserDetect.OS

i added this in the dataOS: property before linux, usign navigator.userAgent and navigator.platform but had no success

```
{
    string: navigator.userAgent,
    substring: "android",
    identity: "android"
},
```

What am I doing wrong? Alternatively if you can offer up a better solution i'm all ears. Essentially what i want the page to do is detect what OS you are using and redirect you to a link specific to each operating system so,

if you are IOS go to link a, if you are android go to link b, if you are blackberry 10 go to link c if you are windows phone go to link c, all others go to link.

Help is much appreciated! I figure the best option is to set up cases but I cant get my head around the OS detection part.

Comment: Is the matching case-sensitive?  That is, does "Android" work where "android" doesn't?

Comment: no i tried them both using Android & android :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the casing to "Android", and it seemed to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fjr5g/4/

```
    {
           string: navigator.userAgent,
           subString: "Android",
           identity: "Android"
    },
```

If this still doesn't work for you (though it should), you can use the string `navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()` and match against `"android"`.

Comment: That's weird! it didnt work when I tried it earlier... Thanks!

Comment: one more question though (two actually), if I have a follow up question do I need to make a seperate thread or can I ask it here? and if I can ask it here, how would I get this to work with windows phone? (I got it working with BB 10, but with windows phone, it spits out Windows instead of Windows Phone ( the windows phone user agent has a windows phone user agent, but I cant get the code to make it happen.)

Comment: If i have to move this to a new thread and mark this as answered please let me know and I will do so :)

Comment: Since the question's rather simple/very related to this, I think it's fine to ask it here. I was able to get it working, and have updated the jsfiddle.

Comment: well this is annoying! I tried the exact same thing and I kept getting windows instead of windows phone!! (same thing with android! Ikept getting linux) but when I copy-pasta your things it works fine O.o weird, i must be doing some kinda typo somethere. Aanywho thanks! i'll mark it as done!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small library that'll return all the data you'd need to know about the browser type here https://github.com/dj10dj100/what_browser. In it you can call

```
if(what.device._android() == true){ 
// do code 
}
```